# Error when getting txt file using fetch()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to get the contents of [this page](https://pastebin.com/raw/QbpKB3Ep), and store it an a variable.

I have the following code:

```js
// fetch the txt file
const fileUrl = 'https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/2facc037'

fetch(fileUrl)
  .then( r => r.text() )
  .then( t => {var message = t} )

console.log(message)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Open developer tools...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives an error. Why?

PS: I have a good reason why I want to store it an a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the `message` variable only within the scope of the last `then` callback. Move the console log there to log the message:

```
// fetch the txt file
const fileUrl = 'https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/2facc037'

fetch(fileUrl)
  .then( r => r.text() )
  .then( t => {
      var message = t;
      console.log(message);
  } )
```

Comment: Okay that worked, but how can I make it out of the global scope??

Comment: That's where it gets tricky since `fetch()` is an async function. What exactly are you trying to do with the variable? It'd probably be best to pass `message` as a parameter to the next function you want to use it with